# What are the risks of using non-ssl connection between server and (externally hosted) database?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, webserver, databases

I am building an application using AWS Lambda and using a MongoDB database hosted directly with MongoDB (Atlas). For some reason, I get an error when trying to connect via SSL and I've been working on it for days without any luck.

What are the risks, I mean real-world risks including scenarios, of using a non-secure connection when connecting to the database?

I guess in theory it's open to man-in-the-middle and if the connection is intercepted somehow they could read the contents of the request, but how would this work practically between AWS Lambda and MongoDB Atlas (hosted within AWS)? Someone would have to have some form of access to the network in order to eavesdrop wouldn't they?

Comment: What you have described is not an "externally hosted database" if both are in AWS.

Comment: Your question becomes about the threats within the AWS network. And that's a bit of an unknown.

Comment: Disclosure is not the only threat if the threat actor is malicious: a malicious threat actor could *change* the data, as well.

Comment: They both utilise AWS but MongoDB manage their databases through their own AWS account and I must access it through a separate host URL which is accessible by anyone (I will try and lock this down to AWS specific IP addresses but obviously within AWS the ip address changes)

Comment: Sure, I get that, but the traffic is not leaving AWS. That means the threat has to be within AWS networks.

Comment: Ok so given the traffic never leaves AWS, is this something you would consider to be a gaping hole in the security of my application?

Comment: I'm saying that it's an unknown.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: giving up is the wrong choice.  Of course there are always limits to how much time you can spend on a given problem - in practice no one has infinite amount of resources to do "all the things", but in my book understanding root issues is a key part of building systems.  It's perfectly reasonable to say "I'm running into issue X, which can be fixed with approach Y, but deploying Y is costly and our current approach is secure enough for our purposes".  It's less reasonable to say "I can't figure it out so we stopped trying".

Comment: Running into issues, unexpected problems, and hiccups is a natural part of this process.  Figuring out how to get to the root cause in such cases is a key skill that we all need to develop.  Everytime you run into a roadblock and figure out how to fix it, you build knowledge in that area.  Doing that many times in many areas is literally how you become an expert in your chosen fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the SSL connection to work, you might want to consider setting up an SSH tunnel between the two servers, and routing the (insecure) connection through the tunnel to secure it.  See https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, the connection between the Server and Database should always be over SSL, whether the network/connection is exposed to the extra world or not. In this case, there could an MITM attack by the person having access to the network. Just remember the principles like 'Segregation of Duties (SoD)', 'Need to Know' and 'Need to Have'. Unauthorized should never have access to confidential information.